# using python and IActiveDesktop to set wallpaper in windows 7

Tags: python, windows

I have been searching for how to use IActiveDesktop to change the wallpaper and have pieced together the following code from various sources.

```
sys.coinit_flags = 0
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
iad = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_ActiveDesktop, None, pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, shell.IID_IActiveDesktop)
iad.SetWallpaper(bmpPath)
iad.ApplyChanges(7)
```

I get the following error:

`pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)`

As I'm unfamiliar with how to use pythoncom I don't really know what I'm doing wrong here.

Please note that I don't want to use SystemParametersInfo as it doesn't have the fade effect that IActiveDesktop apparently has.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the second parameter to `SetWallPaper`, which should always be 0.
This works for me:

```
import pythoncom
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

imagePath = "c:\\temp\\bug.png"

iad = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(shell.CLSID_ActiveDesktop, None,
          pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, shell.IID_IActiveDesktop)
iad.SetWallpaper(imagePath, 0)
iad.ApplyChanges(shellcon.AD_APPLY_ALL)
```

Reference: [IActiveDesktop::ApplyChanges Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776346%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. However it doesn't have the transition effect I was looking for, guess I'll just have to live with it. Thanks again!